# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly after Windows update

Tags: mysql

MySQL will no longer run today after a windows 11 update. I am getting vey little information from the error log, see below. Any ideas ?

```
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.21 started; log sequence number 698629881; transaction id 1864661
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-07-13 17:45:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Look in the Windows Event Viewer for messages from MySQL or mariaDB

Comment: That error log fragment shows a happily running MySQL instance; find the spot where it actually shuts down, I guess.